# Импорт класса из модуля в тест в TypeScript

Tags: typescript, grunt, mocha

Есть файл src/core/version.ts

```
module MyModule.Core {
  /** Version information. */
  export class Version {
    /** The informal version. */
    public static getInformalVersion(): string {
      return "1.0 Beta 1";
    }    
  }
}
export default MyModule.Core.Version;
```

я написал к нему тест test/core/version.test.ts

```
import {assert} from 'chai';
import Version from "../../src/core/version";

describe('Version',()=>{
    it('getInformalVersionTest',()=> {
        let number =Version.getInformalVersion();
    assert.isNotNull(number);
    });
});
```

если запускать тест 
`mocha test --recursive`

то тест проходит без проблем, однако grunt ругается

```
error TS1148: Cannot compile modules unless the '--module' flag is provided.
```

на строчку

```
 export default MyModule.Core.Version;
```

если её убрать, то сборка проекта пройдет, однако тогда тест не видит модуль.

```
TS23006 File './src/core/version.ts' is not a module
```

Подскажите как сделать импорт класса Version в тест version.test.ts

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решен. Вот так нужно:

```
import {assert} from 'chai';
import * as fs from "fs";

var fileContent = fs.readFileSync("./src/core/version.js", "utf8");
if( fileContent.indexOf("exports.MyModule = MyModule;") === -1 )
    fs.appendFileSync('./src/core/version.js', "\n exports.MyModule = MyModule;");

import * as MyModule from "../../src/core/version.js";
import Version = MyModule.MyModule.Core.Version;
describe('Version',()=>{
    it('getInformalVersionTest',()=> {
        let number =Version.getInformalVersion();
    assert.isNotNull(number);
    });
});
```